# How to work on the Mozilla project with emacs and cedet?

Tags: mozilla, cedet, emacs24

I'm working on the Mozilla project, and I use emacs. It's quite a big project, so I tried to use the cedet to help me. I'm not very familiar with the elisp things. So could anybody tell me how can I manage the code space using ede?

btw, I'm using emacs24 and cedet 1.1